# Why do I get an empty form when I start SDK Manager in Android Studio?

Tags: forms, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 2.3.3.  When I start "SDK Manager", either from inside a project, or from the main Android Studio program, I get an empty form.
[image]

I tried this even after rebooting my PC.  Same result. Otherwise, the program works, that is, it compiles and runs simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Android studio and install it again.. or mybe you need to download android studio installer from the website,, maybe your downloaded file missing some important files and dependencies,,

Comment: I've been using this for 9 months now.  Why all of a sudden would this happen?  It's not that important at this time as it's not affecting anything I'm doing.  I'll try it when I get a couple days free.